First layer is thin with voids in the first corner of a rectangular object inside border
Qidi X-Max.  PLA printing temp 200 °C build plate temp 60 °C.
I am using the back of the magnetic plate that came with the machine (the white front is a little worn out from ABS printing. the back is smooth and has worked pretty well.  I am using Elmer's glue stick on the build plate.
The first corner where the inside of the bottom layer is getting filled with diagonal lines leaves a void.  The opposite diagonal corner, where the head is making short traverses is OK.

Not sure where to start. I can't find the "calibration sheet" that came with the printer to set extruder clearance, but a feeler gauge starts to show resistance around 0.55 mm to 0.60 mm.
Some relevant (?) speeds from the config panel:

Print speed: 60 mm/s
Wall speed: 30 mm/s
Top/bottom speed (?): 30 mm/s
Initial layer speed: 20 mm/s

I was able to minimize this by setting Enable Travel Prime, and I also reduced the initial gap to about 0.45 mm.
I will try to reduce the first layer speed from 20 mm/s to 15 mm/s and see if that also helps.

resistance around 0.55 mm to 0.60 mm that is a pretty big gap. Usually, this is paper thickness: "the average thickness of an A4 paper is between 0.05 mm and 0.10 mm", so your initial distance might be too large, the image supports this (lines do not seem to be squished enough).

I made some edits to my original post (but didn't clearly mark them as edits.  i.e. ElableTravelPrime and reducing height to 0.45.  Sounds like I have more room to play with.  texture on bottom layer already looks worlds better.  Thank you Oscar.

You're welcome, just interesting to troubleshoot the problem! 0.45 initial gap is still very large, use plain A4 paper and try again. Some people use business cards, those are a bit thicker. Note that if you use Cura, you can install an add-on to modify the initial gap; it basically moves the whole G-code down. I've used that many times when I was to lazy to use the paper method...
